# Solving first order differential equation numerically

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The problem is of the following form: $\frac{dr}{dt}$ = $f(r)$, so $\frac{1}{f(r)} dr = dt$. My goal is to get some $r(t)$ from this differential equation by numerically integrating this, that is, a value for $r$ at every $t$. The conditions are $r(0) = r_0$ and $r(\infty) = \infty$. The problem I run into is that I am not quite sure what the limits would be to get such values for $r(t)$. Any suggestions on where to go from this would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you have the fact that: $$t=\int\frac{dr}{f(r)}+C$$ which you would then apply initial conditions to in order to find $C$, then if possible you could rearrange the equation to $r$ as a function of $t$ rather than the other way around

Comment: @HenryLee How would I apply the conditions in this case to this indefinite integral?

Comment: you will get a function out in terms of $r$ from this integral, and the integration constant. If you just substitute in the initial conditions then you will be able to work out $C$

Comment: @HenryLee $f(r)$ is a long and difficult function which I can not solve analytically

Comment: In principle, you can compute a table of pairs $r\mapsto t$ using the Simpson method or similar. Then switch the columns of the table and compute intermediate values using the usual table interpolation methods, like linear or quadratic interpolation with the closest pair or triple of $t\mapsto r$ rows of the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this is a first order problem, you do not get to fix two conditions, only one. Once you choose $r(0)=r_0$, the solution is determined for all $t$ and it may or may not satisfy $r(\infty)=\infty$.  The simplest method you can use is Euler's method: you choose equally spaced points $t_0,t_1=t_0+h, t_2=t_0+2h, \cdots$, and build the sequence
$$
\begin{cases}
R_0 = r(t_0)=r_0\\
R_{n+1}=R_n + h f(R_n)
\end{cases}
$$

Naturally, $R_i$ will be the approximate value of $r(t_i)$. You may have to use very small $h$ for precise results but it has the advantage of being very easy to implement. If you want more accurate methods, you may want to lookup Runge-Kutta methods.

In terms of the integral form of the equation this corresponds to say that

$$
r(t+h)= r(t) + \int_t^{t+h}
f(r(s)) \,ds \approx r(t) + h f(r(t)).$$

Answer (score 0):

$\int_{r_0}^{a} \frac{1}{f(r)}dr = t$, with $a = r(t)$.

Now let $F(r)$ be the antiderivative of the integrand.

$F(r(t)) - F(r(0)) = t$. Now if we know how to invert $F(r)$, we can find our $r(t)$.

Comment: $f(r)$ is a long beast, from which I have no clue how to take the anti-derivative, is there some way you could do that numerically?

Comment: Basically what I would do is compute the integral for a variety of different $a$, and find the $a$ which makes this closest to your given value of $t$. I.e. do it by optimisation. I.e. create your objective function (as a fn of $a$) as $[\int_{r_0}^a \frac{1}{f(r)}dr - t]^2$, write this objective function as a parameter in some optimisation routine and the minimum will be at $a = r(t)$.

Note: you should also do the integral numerically, the error will be minimal

Answer (score 0):

Write it as, $r_{t_1}=r_{t_0}+\int_{t_0}^{t_1}f(t)dt$, where $0=t_0\leq t_1\leq\cdots$. Apply your favorite quadrature rule, for instance, $r_{t_1}=0+(t_1-0)\frac{f(t_1)+f(0)}{2}$. This way use it to get $r(t_2)$ and so on.

Comment: How would I get $f(t)$?

Comment: @Smitty Is $f(r)$ known?

Comment: Yes it is known

Comment: But the correct integral equation in that form is $$r_{t_1}=r_{t_0}+\int_{t_0}^{t_1}f(r(t))\,dt$$ where the $r$ in the composition on the right side is unknown. You would actually need a Runge-Kutta method or similar to solve in this unseparated form, in contrast to the cumulative quadrature that is needed in the separated form.

Comment: @LutzL I have been looking at Runge-Kutta methods, but it seems they only work for the form $\dot{y} = f(t,y)$ whereas my function $f$ is independent of $t$.

Comment: @Smitty : $\dot y=F(t,y)=f(y)$ is a part of the general class of ODE, called autonomous ODE. Runge-Kutta works perfectly fine for that.

Comment: @LutzL Ah yes, I have found it, thanks for the help